# How to check that instance member types are the same than the instance interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a config.js file:

```
window.cb_c07d1fb54766d45482d({
    "descriptionMaxLength": 100
});
```

I load it that way:

```
interface TemplateData {
    descriptionMaxLength: number;
}

private getTemplateData(): Promise<TemplateData> {
    return new Promise<TemplateData>((resolve, reject) => {
        (window as any)[cb_c07d1fb54766d45482d] = (data: any) => { // the callback func is hardcoded here in order to simplify the reading
            resolve(data); // implicit cast
        };

        scriptInclude(url);
    });
}
```

This code works great, but if make a mistake in my config, it will not break:

```
window.cb_c07d1fb54766d45482d({
    "descriptionMaxLength": "break my code", // mistake
});
```

Here, the descriptionMaxLength loaded will be a string, even though it is described as a number in the interface.

So, to ensure that the config file is valid, I can do:

```
private checkType(data: TemplateData): boolean {
    return typeof data.descriptionMaxLength === "number";
}
```

But I see 2 problems doing that:

1. it is a lot of boring work if my config file is heavy (like 200 lines)
2. if I decide to change a type but I forget to change it in this
   method, I introduced a bug.

So I was wondering if there is a generic method in Typescript to ensure that the object's members have the same types than the interface it implements ?

Thank you for your help guys !

Comment: Where do you link your config to the main file? How do they connect?

Comment: @Aron within the promise block,after the line "return new Promise"

Comment: The problem is that TypeScript has no idea what `(window as any)[callbackFunc]` will be at runtime. Can you not import the config file at compile time?

Comment: Ah yes I unterstand the issue, but I can't load it at compile time, because I target the right file depending of the client id at runtime

Comment: If you can't specify the function at compile time then TypeScript won't be able to help you I'm afraid. TS is only a compiler so it has no way of knowing what will happen at runtime.

Comment: Yes it seems you're right :) Thank you for your time @Aron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to force tsc/IDE to check the validity of the config file instead of you. Declare your settings structure alongside actual settings in `config.ts` file like this:

```
export interface ISettings
{
    descriptionMaxLength: number;
}

export const Settings: ISettings =
{
    descriptionMaxLength : 123,
};
```

And then later in your code import them like so:

```
import {Settings} from './config';
```

If you for some reason do not use modules you can still use similar approach as long as `config.ts` will be part of you project and get compiled. As soon as someone will make a mistake - your build will be broken and IDE will complain aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript feature called [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in order to declare an extra object in Window.

```
interface Window {
    cb_c07d1fb54766d45482d: (config: {
        descriptionMaxLength: number
    }) => any;
}
interface TemplateData {
    descriptionMaxLength: number;
}

window.cb_c07d1fb54766d45482d({
    descriptionMaxLength: 100
});

function getTemplateData(): Promise<TemplateData> {
    return new Promise<TemplateData>((resolve, reject) => {
        window.cb_c07d1fb54766d45482d = (data: any) => { 
            resolve(data);
        };
    });
}
```

I think something like this example will work for you.